# Change the font color of all users (nickname) to red

Tags: java, sockets

I have been working on a Java chat application. I am trying to change the color of all users' "nicknames" to red, but when I try to change that not only the nickname color changes to red but the text also (the text that the user has written).

How do I change the color of the nicknames only?

```
public Gui()
{
    // constructing form
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Chat");
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent arg0) {
            currentRoom.unsubscribe(Gui.this);
            frame.dispose();
        }
    });
    // messages field
    frame.add(new JScrollPane(messages = new JTextPane()));
    messages.setEditable(false);

    // creating styles
    messages.setBackground(Color.white);

    Style msg = messages.addStyle("message", null);
    StyleConstants.setForeground(msg, Color.black);

    msg = messages.addStyle("my-message", null);
    StyleConstants.setForeground(msg, Color.blue);

    msg = messages.addStyle("join", null);
    StyleConstants.setForeground(msg, Color.gray);
    StyleConstants.setItalic(msg, true);

    msg = messages.addStyle("part", null);
    StyleConstants.setForeground(msg, Color.gray);
    StyleConstants.setItalic(msg, true);

    // input panel
    final JTextField input = new JTextField();

    ActionListener sendMessage = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            sendMessage(input.getText());
            input.setText("");
        }
    };

    input.addActionListener(sendMessage);

    JButton send = new JButton("Send");
    send.addActionListener(sendMessage);

    JPanel bottom = new JPanel();
    bottom.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    bottom.add(input);
    bottom.add(send, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
    frame.add(bottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    frame.setSize(480, 320);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private void appendLine(String line, String style)
{
    try {
        messages.getDocument().insertString(
            messages.getDocument().getEndPosition().getOffset(),
            line + "\n", messages.getStyle(style));
    }
    catch (BadLocationException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public void subscribeTo(Room room)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    this.nick = "User" + random.nextInt(100);
    room.subscribe(this);
    this.currentRoom = room;
}

// -- events

private void sendMessage(String text) 
{
    currentRoom.publish(this, text);
    appendLine("["+ nick +"]: "+ text, "my-message");
}

public void joined(String nick) 
{
    appendLine("** "+ nick +" joined chat", "join");
}

public void parted(String nick) 
{
    appendLine("** "+ nick +" left us", "part");
}

public void receive(String nick, String message) 
{
    appendLine("["+ nick +"]: "+ message, "message");
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
    throws UnknownHostException, IOException 
{
    Gui gui = new Gui();
    System.out.println("Conncting to server...");
    Room room = new ClientTransport(new Socket(args[0], 1024));
    System.out.println("Connected, registering...");
    gui.subscribeTo(room);
}

public String getNick() 
{
    return nick;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, you need to create a new style:

```
msg = messages.addStyle("nick", null);
StyleConstants.setForeground(msg, Color.red);
StyleConstants.setItalic(msg, true);
```

Now, you have to apply it when writing the nickname. It means that you have to rewrite all the lines that print the nickname and some text into two consecutive lines like this:

```
appendLine("["+ nick +"]: "+ text, "my-message");
```

becomes

```
appendLine("["+ nick +"]: ", "nick");
appendLine(text, "my-message");
```

Comment: Don't use the ">" for tagging code. Select the code and then click on the `{}` button.